# How use signal in base class from all inherited class in qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-quick, qtquickcontrols2, busyindicator

I have a qt quick 2 application,I have base class for my c++ classes

```
class ManagerEngine : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit ManagerEngine(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    bool isProcessing();
    void setIsProcssing(bool isProcessing);
signals:    
    void isProcessingChanged(bool isProcessing);
private:
     bool m_IsProccessing;
};
```

I have many class that has inherited from above class

```
class BookManager : public ManagerEngine
{
};

void BookManager::getList(bool refreshList){
    setIsProcssing(true);
    //get data from server
    setIsProcssing(false);
}
```

Now in thease classes I want to show `BusyIndicator` when the method is getting some data from server.

**BookPage.qml**

```
BookManager{
    id: bm
    onIsProcessingChanged: {
        busyIndicator.visible=isProcessing; // busyIndicator is in main.qml
    }
}
```

**CategoryPage.qml**

```
CategoryManager{
    id: cm
    onIsProcessingChanged: {
        busyIndicator.visible=isProcessing;
    }
}
```

**QuestionPage.qml**

```
QuestionManager{
    id: qm
    onIsProcessingChanged: {
        busyIndicator.visible=isProcessing;
    }
}

//I have many class like : login signup and ... inherited from base class
```

**main.qml**

```
BusyIndicator{
    id:busyIndicator        
}
```

All works ok in `BookPage.qml` and ... (above) and in thease page busyIndicator will display.But I want do this on time.

I tryed this: I use base class`ManagerEngine` for display `BusyIndicator`

I want to display busyIndicator Like below.(i Declared Base class in main page.Now if i open BookPage.qml for display book list,now the busyIndicator must be visible

**main.qml**

```
ManagerEngine{
    id: me
    onIsProcessingChanged: {
        progressIndicator.visible=isProcessing;
    }
}
BusyIndicator{
    id:busyIndicator        
}
```

But It don't work.Is there another way for doing this work(for example can i use static keyword)

Comment: Personally for me, this question is not clear. Just want to be clear, when you say `BusyIndicator`, you mean that the `progressIndicator.visible` is equal to `isProcessing` ? Also, mention the error that you face, or what is not working as expected.

Comment: I do not understand you, explain yourself better. You indicate that the implementation in the derived class works, but not in the Base class, which contradicts your title.

Comment: @eyllanesc when i use in inherited class (BookManager) in BookPage.qml ,busyindicator will display.But i want call getlist in BookPage.qml and the busyindicator in main.qml will visible

Comment: @mohsen 
Do you want that if any of the objects in the classes that inherit from ManagerEngine change the status of setIsProcssing, the objects of the ManagerEngine class are also notified?

Comment: @eyllanesc  yes,and i want use this for display busyIndicator or show message to user or ...

Comment: @eyllanesc I want do the work one time,for example in any class when i call a method for get data,with signal in base class show busyindicator

Comment: @mohsen I recommend you edit your question and add at least my comment in a personalized way since other users are not understanding you.

Answer (score 1):

This won't ever work, because those classes seem to work in the main thread, and when the processing is being done, no user interface updates are taking place, and your application is frozen.

In all cases, the solution has to begin with making the busy indicator a proper property - this will magically fix your Qt Quick problems, and you can simply bind to the property and not have to use the signal explicitly at all. That's what property notifications are for, and QML handles them for you. You also don't want the setter to be public - this is internal, read-only state. You also want const-correct signatures.

After fixing all of the problems, we get:

```
class ManagerEngine : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(bool isProcessing READ isProcessing NOTIFY isProcessingChanged)
public:
    using QObject::QObject; //for C++14 & up
    bool isProcessing() const;
    Q_SIGNAL void isProcessingChanged(bool);
protected:
    void setIsProcessing(bool);
private:
    bool m_isProccessing = false;
};

/// This method is not thread-safe
void ManagerEngine::setIsProcessing(bool p) {
  if (p == m_isProcessing) return;
  m_isProcessing = p; // precondition of the signal
  return emit isProcessingChanged(m_isProcessing);
}

/// This method is not thread-safe
bool ManagerEngine::isProcessing() const {
  return m_isProcessing;
}
```

If you want the processing to be a state shared across all instances of the manager engine, then make it a property of the class, not of the object. In C++, a `static` member declaration means that it's a class member, not object member.

#### Interface

```
class ManagerEngine : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(bool isProcessing READ isProcessing NOTIFY isProcessingChanged)
public:
    using QObject::QObject; //for C++14 & up
    ~ManagerEngine() override;
    bool isProcessing() const;
    Q_SIGNAL void isProcessingChanged(bool);
protected:
    void setIsProcessing(bool);
private:
    bool m_isProcessing = false; // per-object
    static QAtomicInt m_processingCount; // per-class
};
```

#### Implementation

```
QAtomicInt ManagerEngine::m_processingCount;

ManagerEngine::~MangerEngine() {
  setIsProcessing(false);
  // Perhaps it'd be more appropriate instead to simply
  // Q_ASSERT(!m_isProcessing) if the engine should not be destroyed
  // during processing.
}

// This method is not thread-safe, but multiple engines can
// reside in different threads.
void ManagerEngine::setIsProcessing(bool p) {
  if (p == m_isProcessing) return;
  int const delta = p ? (+1) : (-1);
  auto count = m_processingCount.load();
  Q_ASSERT(count >= 0);
  Q_ASSERT(p || count > 0);
  m_isProcessing = p;
  while (!m_processingCount.testAndSetOrdered(count, count+delta)) {
    count = m_processingCount.load();
  }
  // The signal will be emitted only when the global state changes,
  // and exactly once per global state change.
  if ((count > 0) != ((count+delta) > 0))
    emit isProcessingChanged(count > 0);
  return;
}

// Note: Due to data races, it is not guaranteed that the result of
// this method is the same as the parameter in the isProcessingChanged
// signal. Only the signal's parameter is guaranteed to change state
// in a race-free fashion, i.e. always toggle (alternate) and never repeat.
bool ManagerEngine::isProcessing() const {
  auto const count = m_processingCount.load();
  Q_ASSERT(count >= 0);
  Q_ASSERT(!m_isProcessing || count > 0);
  return count > 0;
}
```

Comment: The problem is another, the asker is not very clear in his question but in the comments it is, he has a class called ManagerEngine, and let's say that there are objects of that class called manager1 and manager2. Of that class ManagerEngine has derived classes such as BookManager, and let's say that there are objects bookmanager1, bookmanager2, so the asker requires that if you change the isProcessing property in bookmanagerX you will also be notified by the managerY.

Comment: @eyllanesc But to begin with, the signal-using pattern is wrong anyway, QML handles these notifications automatically when you bind to the source object's property. Anyway, I'm answering the question, not the comments. The asker is free to edit the question to reflect reality.

Comment: I agree with what it indicates, what I say is that the asker wanted to explain that in his question but he has not done it correctly, he confused me because he indicates that it works in the derived classes but not in the base class, so I said it is contradictory, do not you think? That is why I made my query to understand the asker better.